# Apply function to every column value of each row using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For this dataframe :

```
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
data = np.array([[1,2,2] , [4,5,4], [7,8,18]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
df2['C']
```

If the difference between consecutive rows for column C is <= 2 then the previous and current row should be returned. So I'm attempting to filter out rows where difference for previous row > 2.

So expecting these array values to be returned :

```
    [1,2,2] 

    [4,5,4]

    [7,8,18]
```

I'm attempting to implement this functionality using the shift function :

```
df2[(df2.A - df2.shift(1).A >= 2)]
```

The result of which is :

```
    A   B   C
1   4   5   4
2   7   8   18
```

I think need to apply function to each row in order to achieve this ?

Update :

Alternative use case :

```
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
data = np.array([[1,2,2] , [2,5,3], [7,8,16]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
df2[df2.A.diff().shift(-1) >= 2]
```

Returned is :

```
    A   B   C
1   2   5   3
```

but expecting

```
    A   B   C
1   2   5   3
1   7   8   16
```

so in this case expecting the next and current row to be returned as difference between 2 & 8 in
`2  5   3` & `8   8   18` is > 2

Update 2 :

Edge case : if the last value being compared is < 2 then the row is ignored

```
columns = ['A','B', 'C']
data = np.array([[2,2,2] , [3,5,3], [5,8,16], [6,8,16]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)

df2[df2.A.diff().shift(-1).ffill() >= 2]
```

returns :

```
A   B   C
1   3   5   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and last `NaN`s replace by `ffill`:

```
a = df2[df2.A.diff().shift(-1).ffill() >= 2]
#same as
a = df2[df2.A.diff().shift(-1).ffill().ge(2)]
print (a)

   A  B   C
1  2  5   3
2  7  8  16
```

Comment: In this logic is not necessary return all 3 rows in first sample?

Comment: your right, ive further updated question for clarity, thanks.